# How can i get the latest Business Central Docker image?

Tags: powershell, azure-container-instances, dynamics-business-central

I  am deploying to Azure a Business Central Docker image . where can i find the details for --image tag

I am using

```
   --image mcr.microsoft.com/businesscentral/sandbox:base (but this give msg its over 90 days 
                                                                                   old)
```

I also use

```
      --image microsoft/bcsandbox:latest
```

and it still gives error:

You are trying to run a container which is more than 90 days old.

```
Microsoft recommends that you always run the latest version of our containers.

Set the environment variable ACCEPT_OUTDATED to 'Y' if you want to run this container anyway.
```

How can i run the latest version without having to set the flag ACCEPT_OUTDATED ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images are no longer being maintained. This is the reason you get an outdated version. You can read more about that in [these blog posts](https://freddysblog.com/tag/artifacts/).

If you want to host the latest version in Azure you will have to create a Windows Server with Containers and then use `BcContainerHelper` to build and run the required container image.